# Ajax timeout retry without waiting to timeout again

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to resend ajax every 5 second if something went wrong but for some reason when i simulate offline connection with Chrom ajax request is called nonstop wtihout waiting 5 seconds after each request.

What im doing wrong ? btw im not getting any of thoes console.logs in my browser console

```
    $('#filters-ajax').one('click', function(){

      var product_id = "<?php echo isset($set_id) ? $set_id : NULL; ?>";

      $.ajax({
        url: "index.php?route=catalog/product/getFiltersGroup&token=<?php echo $token ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: '&product_id='+product_id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        timeout: 5000,
        beforeSend: function(){
          $('#btn-product-filter-groups').attr('disabled', true);
        },
        success: function(data){
          $('#btn-product-filter-groups').attr('disabled', false);
        },
        error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
          console.log(xmlhttprequest);
          console.log(textstatus);
          console.log(message);
          
          $.ajax(this);
        }
      });
    })
```

Comment: You set 50 seconds instead 5

Comment: @jgu7man i change it to 5 sec. but this wont fix the problem that sending request nonstop without waiting for timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timeout` property of the `$.ajax()` options object does not define a delayed execution. Instead it is used to cancel a request if it has not been fulfilled within the specified time.

If you want repeated AJAX calls with a defined time between them to happen you will have to set it up with `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`.

Here is a snippet with `setInterval()`:

```js
const url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/";
const iv=setInterval(()=>
$.ajax({
    url: url+Math.ceil(Math.random()*50),
    /* type: "POST",
    data: '&product_id='+product_id, */
    dataType: 'JSON',
    /* beforeSend: function(){
      $('#btn-product-filter-groups').attr('disabled', true);
    }, */
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data.title)
    },
    error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
      console.log(xmlhttprequest);
      console.log(textstatus);
      console.log(message);          
      // $.ajax(this);
    }
  }), 1000);
document.querySelector("button").onclick=()=>clearInterval(iv)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.2.min.js"></script>
<button>stop AJAX</button>
```